# Relativistic Electric Potetnial

Tags: electromagnetism, potential, relativity

Suppose you have a particle of charge q circling the z axis in the xy plane. The orbit is centered at the origin and has a radius of $r_0$. The angular frequency of the orbit is $\omega$. Position of the charge is given by $\vec{r}=r_0\cos{\omega t}\hat{i}+r_0\sin{\omega t}\hat{j}. $

What is the relativistically correct Electric Potential at point (0,0,$z$) on the z axis?

I get two answers, and I'm not sure if either of them is correct.

1) For a given $z$, the distance to the charge at any point on its orbit is a constant, $\sqrt{z^2+r_0^2}$. Since that distance doesn't change despite the time dependence of charge location, we can still use the the standard formula, $V=\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0\sqrt{z^2+r_0^2}}$.

2) Were the charge not moving, the expression from #1 would be appropriate. We'd have the Electric potential, and the Magnetic Potential would be zero. That we have motion implies a Vector Magnetic Potential. The 4-potential is $(V/c,\vec{A})$. It's magnitude, $-V^2/c^2+A^2$ is a Lorentz scalar. So a frame in which $\vec{A}$ is zero to one in which it is not, requires a corresponding change in $V$. If the magnitude of $\vec{A}$ increases, then $V$ must increase.

In the case of a uniformly moving charge, we can get the relativistically correct potential by taking the potential from the stationary case and replacing the spatial dimension, the distance from location of field point to current location of charge,  with the vector projection of the vector from field point to current charge point projected onto the vector from field point to the location of the particle at the retarded time.

Applying that procedure to the current case yields a distance of : 
$$\frac{z^2+r_0^2\cos{\omega\left(\frac{\sqrt{z^2+r_0^2}}{c}\right)}}{\sqrt{z^2+r_0^2}}$$

and so a potential of:

$$V=\frac{q\sqrt{z^2+r_0^2}}{4\pi\epsilon_0\left(z^2+r_0^2\cos{\omega\left(\frac{\sqrt{z^2+r_0^2}}{c}\right)}\right)}$$

This yields an increase in the potential. I'm not sure if it has anything else going for it.

Any thoughts?